# Javascript color guessing game

Tags: javascript, html

I'm practicing my javascript coding by writing a color guessing game where there is a set array of colors and one will randomly be selected as the target color.  The user will then be prompted to select a color.  The selection goes through some criteria and if correct the background color of the page changes to match the correct color.  Those are the basics of the game.  I can't even get the alerts of the code to run.  I have no idea of the problem.  Thank you.

Here's the code I have.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body onload="do_game()">
        <script> 
            alert("ok");
            var colors = ["coral", "olive", "khaki", "lime", "red", "maroon", "yellow", "green", "orchid"];
            var alpha_colors = colors.sort();
            return alpha_colors;
            var finished = false;
            var guesses = 0;

            function do_game(){
                alert("ok so far");
                var num_colors = colors.length-1;
                var target = colors[math.floor.random()*num_colors]
                do{
                    var color_guess=prompt("I am thinking of these colors \n\n"+alpha_colors+"What color am I thinking of?");
                    guesses += 1;
                    finished=checkguess();
                } while(finished=false);
            }

            function checkguess(){
                if(colors.indexOf(color_guess)=-1) {
                    alert("Sorry.  I don't recognize your color. \n\n Please try again. ");
                    return false;
                }
                if(color_guess<target) {
                    alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct. \n\n Hint: your color is alphabetically lower than mine");
                    return false;
                }
                if(color_guess>target) {
                    alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct. \n\n Hint: your color is alphabetically higher than mine");
                    return false;
                }
                alert("Congratulations! You have guessed the color! \n\n It took you "+guesses+"guesses to finish the game! \n\n You can see the color in the background");                     
                return true;
            }
            style.background-color=target
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement` on line 10, followed by `Uncaught ReferenceError: do_game is not defined` on 3 (edit: adjusted line numbers, snippets don't need doctype/html//bodys)

Comment: Open the browser's JavaScript console, and fix the errors it reports.

Answer (score 1):

You made some beginner mistakes.

1. After you use "return" you end everything in the current scope. So
   when you return alpha_colors at line 4 your code after that line
   will never run.
2. Thats not how you compare strings alphabetically.
3. math.floor.random() is not how you make a random number. Next time
   try Math.floor(Math.random()*maxNumber);
4. When you compare two things use == or ===. Never "="! "=" in programming is different than "=" in Math. Use "=" when you want to set value to a variable and use "==" when you want to compare two things.

```js
alert("ok");
var colors = ["black",
  "green",
  "yellow"
];
var alpha_colors = colors.sort();
var finished = false;
var guesses = 0;
var target = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha_colors.length)];

function do_game() {
  alert("ok so far");
  var color_guess = prompt("I am thinking of these colors \n\n" + alpha_colors + "What color am I thinking of?");
  guesses += 1;
  checkguess(color_guess);
}

function checkguess(color_guess) {
  if (color_guess == "stop") {
    return false;
  }
  if (colors.indexOf(color_guess) == -1) {
    alert("Sorry.  I don't recognize your color. \n\n Please try again");
    do_game();
  }
  if (color_guess < target) {
    alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct. \n\n Hint: your color is alphabetically lower than mine");
    do_game();
  }
  if (color_guess > target) {
    alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct. \n\n Hint: your color is alphabetically higher than mine");
    do_game();
  }
  if (colors.indexOf(color_guess) >= 0) {
    alert("Congratulations! You have guessed the color! \n\n It took you " + guesses + "guesses to finish the game! \n\n You can see the color in the background");
  }
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = target;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body onload="do_game()">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 4 of your script tag has a return statement:

```
return alpha_colors;
```

Return statements can only be inside of functions. Also, you are referencing the function "do_game" before you have actually defined it.